# Laravel, best way to do the relation

Tags: sql, laravel

I have this problem: some users (user_id) have access to reports (report_id), but for a limited time only (in days, days_count) for any report, but each report can be accessed only a certain amount of tries (report_count) during the days_count.

In one table, the logic would be this:

```
One Table
---------
id - user_id - report_id - report_count - days_count
1 - 5 - 1 - 5 - 7
2 - 5 - 2 - 3 - 7
3 - 3 - 1 - 4 - 10
```

The first row would be read as: "the user with user_id 5, has access to report_id 1, he has 5 access left, and 7 days left for any access"
etc.

I was thinking on make 2 tables like this:

```
Table 1
---------
id - user_id - report_id - report_count
1 - 5 - 1 - 5
2 - 5 - 2 - 3
3 - 3 - 1 - 4

Table 2
---------
id - user_id - days_count
1 - 5 - 7
2 - 2 - 10
```

Using that logic of 2 tables, how could I use the Laravel relations to establish my, relations?

Comment: The `days_count` should, in my opinion, be replaced by a datetime column containing the datetime where the user loses access to the reports. Without a `created_at` column (or similar), your current database design won't work as the `days_count` don't update themselves each day. -- Best design would probably be your one-table-design (with my suggested change) together with another table that logs the access of users to reports (i.e. when did a user access which report), as it gives you the most information and allows you to calculate the state very easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [belongsToMany relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with additional pivot fields.
Your User model should have the relation method to reports like this:

```
/**
 * User belongs to many (many-to-many) Reports.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function reports()
{
    // belongsToMany(RelatedModel, pivotTable, thisKeyOnPivot = report_id, otherKeyOnPivot = user_id)
    return $this->belongsToMany(Report::class)->withPivot('report_count', 'days_count');
}
```

The Report model would then have the following counterpart

```
/**
 * Report belongs to many (many-to-many) Users.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function users()
{
    // belongsToMany(RelatedModel, pivotTable, thisKeyOnPivot = user_id, otherKeyOnPivot = report_id)
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('report_count', 'days_count');
}
```

Comment: `withPivot('report_count', 'days_count')` those are my example Tables 1 and 2? Both answers are helping me a lot, jesus.

Comment: this are the additional fields in your first example "One Table"

Comment: Hm, I get it. So I have to use only one table ("One Table"), a pivot table, without that "id" field that I put in the example. Then I can access to the relations with you answer, and get the reports of the User as Ross Wilson mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Exactly. You would have only the pivot table. You can access the pivot data by `$report->pivot->report_count;` or query them by `$user->reports()->wherePivot('report_count', 1);`

Answer (score 2):

For something like this you would use a [BelongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between `User` and `Report` where the first table in your example is the pivot table.

I would also suggest changing the `days_count` to be a timestamp as you then don't need to update the `days_count` at the start/end of each day (assuming that's what you're doing).

---

Then for getting reports that a User has access to would look something like:

```php
$reports = $user->reports()
    ->whereDate('access_until', '>=', now())
    ->where('report_count', '>=', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: You are right on the timestamp. In front, the admin will put in a `input` the days on number, but the table has to be timestamp.

Comment: You could simply calculate what the timestamp should be when the admin inputs the number of days e.g. `now()->addDays($request->input('days'))`.